# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection does not contain a definition for Query with dapper and c#

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

The following code when compiling gives the error message below:

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Query' and no extension method 'Query' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have added Dapper using the nuget packager.

Any ideas?
Thanks,

**CODE:**

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    Member customer = sqlConnection.Query<Member>("SELECT * FROM member");
    return customer;
}
```

Comment: You are most likely missing a using statement at the beginning of your file where the Query extension method is defined.

Comment: I think it's 'using Dapper;'

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to place a using statement in your .cs file to make the Dapper extension methods available.

```
using ...;
using Dapper;
using ...;
```

Comment: This should be part of Dapper docs. I don't understand why they assume that people should know this.

Comment: just spent 30 minutes on this T_T